# Изменение CSS через JQuery

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить значение CSS свойства при помощи JQuery, или JS. Проблема в том, что стандартный .css() меняет стиль только заданного(ых) элемента(ов):

```js
$('.painted').css('background-color', 'var(#d63031)'); // Меняет цвет на красный
$('div').addClass('painted') // А потом добавляет блоку класс
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.painted {
 background-color: #00b894; /* Зелёный */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

То есть в таком случае .css() не сработает, т. к. присваивание класса происходит после его изменения. Можно ли как-то поменять именно CSS код через JS/ JQuery?

Comment: "чтобы свойство изменилось именно в CSS файле" - ??

Comment: Попытался описать проблему понятнее

Comment: вы не стиль как таковой для класса меняете описанный в css, а находите на странице элементы с данным классом и им изменяете стиль.

Comment: А можно как-то сделать так, чтобы менять именно стиль в css?

Comment: нельзя да и смысла в этом нет. вы чего добавиться то хотите? строчки местами поменяйте, и увидите результат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*все смешалось в доме Облонских*

вы в корне неверно трактуете происходящее. Насколько я понимаю, вы убеждены в том, что вот есть  у вас класс `.painted` в css. Вы якобы берете его `$(".painted")` и меняете его настройку. Потом будто бы добавляете этот измененный класс к диву.

На самом деле в указанном коде вы ищите на странице все элементы разметки у которых есть класс `.painted` (таковых в примере нет) и этим элементам изменяете css-свойство.